# Testing using YOLO version 2

Tags: computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo

I get the following error while running yolo v2. Yolo and tiny yolo works fine. Any leads will be appreciated

```
./darknet detector test ./cfg/voc.data ./cfg/yolo-voc.cfg ./yolo-     voc.weights data/dog.jpg
layer filters size input output
0 conv 32 3 x 3 / 1 416 x 416 x 3 -> 416 x 416 x 32
1 max 2 x 2 / 2 416 x 416 x 32 -> 208 x 208 x 32
2 conv 64 3 x 3 / 1 208 x 208 x 32 -> 208 x 208 x 64
3 max 2 x 2 / 2 208 x 208 x 64 -> 104 x 104 x 64
4 conv 128 3 x 3 / 1 104 x 104 x 64 -> 104 x 104 x 128
5 conv 64 1 x 1 / 1 104 x 104 x 128 -> 104 x 104 x 64
6 conv 128 3 x 3 / 1 104 x 104 x 64 -> 104 x 104 x 128
7 max 2 x 2 / 2 104 x 104 x 128 -> 52 x 52 x 128
8 conv 256 3 x 3 / 1 52 x 52 x 128 -> 52 x 52 x 256
9 conv 128 1 x 1 / 1 52 x 52 x 256 -> 52 x 52 x 128
10 conv 256 3 x 3 / 1 52 x 52 x 128 -> 52 x 52 x 256
11 max 2 x 2 / 2 52 x 52 x 256 -> 26 x 26 x 256
12 conv 512 3 x 3 / 1 26 x 26 x 256 -> 26 x 26 x 512
13 conv 256 1 x 1 / 1 26 x 26 x 512 -> 26 x 26 x 256
14 conv 512 3 x 3 / 1 26 x 26 x 256 -> 26 x 26 x 512
15 conv 256 1 x 1 / 1 26 x 26 x 512 -> 26 x 26 x 256
16 conv 512 3 x 3 / 1 26 x 26 x 256 -> 26 x 26 x 512
17 max 2 x 2 / 2 26 x 26 x 512 -> 13 x 13 x 512
18 conv 1024 3 x 3 / 1 13 x 13 x 512 -> 13 x 13 x1024
19 conv 512 1 x 1 / 1 13 x 13 x1024 -> 13 x 13 x 512
20 conv 1024 3 x 3 / 1 13 x 13 x 512 -> 13 x 13 x1024
21 conv 512 1 x 1 / 1 13 x 13 x1024 -> 13 x 13 x 512
22 conv 1024 3 x 3 / 1 13 x 13 x 512 -> 13 x 13 x1024
23 conv 1024 3 x 3 / 1 13 x 13 x1024 -> 13 x 13 x1024
24 Killed
```

Comment: @arvids said: "If you have solved it, please post your own answer. From my experience this error occurs when you run out of RAM, or maybe storage space."

Comment: I encountered the same problem, but using tiny YOLO worked fine. So maybe it's a memory issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in your project folder then your command will be

```
./darknet detector test cfg/voc.data cfg/yolo-voc.cfg yolo-voc.weights data/dog.jpg
```

I hope this helps...
Check your `.weights` file name

Answer (score 1):

This error sometimes comes because of memory issue. Try freeing up some space in your system's RAM. Or you can try changing your configuration file ./cfg/yolo-voc.cfg

Change the following parameters:

batch size:1

subdivision:1

This reduces the overhead of processing a large batch size. Later you can try increasing it slowly for training purposes.

Otherwise, it may be a problem of ARCH parameter in Makefile. It should be set according to the GPU you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `./darknet detect cfg/yolo-voc.cfg voc.weights data/dog.jpg`. If you still get errors, you should check your .weights file.

Comment: Thank you..I am new here, not really familiar with the rules for answering

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration file change the batch size and subdivision , make them equal to 1 , 1 
I guess this is an memory problem